# How to bind to this so I can properly call setState in React in this coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, coffeescript

So I have some react code in coffeescript like the below code.  *_fetchKitesDone* retrieves data properly via AJAX, but the render always ends up showing "Loading data..." which I suspect means setState is not firing properly and I think it has to do with the fact that I am not binding to the react component's "this" scope.

How do I do this in the code below? Or if that's not the issue, then what is?

```
@ChartContainer = React.createClass
  # Display name used for debugging
  displayName: "ChartContainer"

  # set initial state before mounting component
  getInitialState: ->
    #some state
    fetchedData: false
    kitesData: []

  componentDidMount: ->
    # fetch the data
    @_fetchKites({})

  _fetchKites: (data) ->
    $.ajax
      url: "/kites.json"
      dataType: 'json'
      data: data
    .done @_fetchKitesDone
    .fail @_fetchDealsFail

  # If the AJAX call is successful ...
  _fetchKitesDone: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
    # Change component state & cause children to render again
    labels = []
    kiteValues = []
    for key of data
      labels.push(key)
      kiteValues.push(data[key])
    stringData = {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [
        {
          fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
          strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
          pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
          pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
          data : kiteValues
        }
      ]
    }
    @setState
      fetchedData: true
      kitesData: stringData

  # If errors in AJAX call ...
  _fetchDealsFail: (xhr, status, err) =>
    console.error @props.url, status, err.toString()

  render: ->
     if (@state.kitesData.length > 0)
      <div>
        in here
       </div>
     else
       <div>Loading data...</div>
```

Comment: Your functions are bound properly. Leave them as-is. The problem is that `stringData` is an object, not an array. In your render code you are checking for `{}.length` which always returns undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right `this` value inside `$.ajax` is not your component. You need to do something like this:

```
_fetchKites: (data) ->
    $.ajax
      url: "/kites.json"
      dataType: 'json'
      data: data
    .done (data, textStatus, jqXHR) => 
       @_fetchKitesDone(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    .fail (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) => 
       @_fetchDealsFail(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown )
```

Comment: I figured it out thanks (I assume you are responding to my deleted comment)